# PHP - Executing a command at user-entered time

Tags: php, time

What I'm trying to achieve is the following:

A User enters a time as e.g.: "13:45" into a textfield, which will be saved in a variable and when this time is reached, it should execute a command. (Every day at the entered time!)

Is this possible at all?
If yes: How? :-)

I read about "Cronjob", but if I understood it correctly, this only gives the possibility to enter a fix time when to execute anything.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `at` can schedule one-shot jobs at specific times. cron is more for repeating jobs where the repeat interval can be easily defined.

Comment: You need a cronjob that runs a script that monitors (on a repeated interval) a database full of one time tasks and executes them. Just like Arnold in Terminator 2.

Comment: @mkaatman: I like your idea, come to think of it, minute crons do not sound bad at all (unless the script takes more than a minute to run)

Comment: hrm... I was hoping that this could be achieved without a database. you see a chance for that?

Comment: A database will make it easier, but there's nothing forcing you to have a DB. As plain text file containing the timestamp will do; as long as you can have Cron run a PHP program which can then check whether the time has arrived, it doesn't matter how that time is stored.

Comment: Well, I guess I'll give my best to solve that with the database. :-) Thanks a lot for your help, everyone!